# Duplicate column names in BigQuery when selecting twice within the same table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to perform the following query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r1`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r1"
  )
  AS TAB_1,
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r2`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r2"
  )
  AS TAB_2
WHERE TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date
```

It is basically a selection on the same table applying different condition rules, with the aim to then create a view.
However, I get the following error: `Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): date`

Do you have any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: `date as date_r1` and `date as date_r2` should fix it (you'll need to change the `join` condition too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly, your `SELECT *` will just get all columns from TAB_1 and TAB_2, and in both cases, you have the date field.

```
SELECT TAB_1.*, TAB_2.grob_r2 FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r1`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r1"
  )
  AS TAB_1,
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r2`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r2"
  )
  AS TAB_2
WHERE TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date
```

In your case, your join condition is an equality, but if you wanted to get the date from TAB_2 as well in your results, or if you want to get all columns from TAB_2, whatever they are, you could do something like

`SELECT TAB_1.*, TAB_2.* EXCEPT(date), TAB_2.date AS tab_2_date FROM ...`

edit: To help you with the FULL JOIN question.

```
SELECT TAB_1.*, TAB_2.grob_r2 FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r1`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r1"
  )
  AS TAB_1 FULL JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r2`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r2"
  )
  AS TAB_2
ON TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is now working as an INNER JOIN, selecting only rows when both selections returns a value. Eventually, how can I get a FULL JOIN behaviour?

Comment: I'd recommend you using an explicit JOIN clause, rather than a comma join. 
I will add that code as part of my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks again. The only problem that I am noticing is that I don't get the col `date` populated by the second selection. Basically, in my scenario, the date is working aa a pivot element.

Comment: That is quite a different query that you want mate. Feels we went out of topic here. As for your initial question, I think is sorted. If you want help with the second bit, maybe open a new question with that precise info and I can give you a hand

Answer (score 1):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Then, BigQuery allows you to select full records.  I usually recommend that approach:

```
SELECT TAB_1, TAB_2
FROM (SELECT date, grob as grob_r1
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r1'
     ) TAB_1 JOIN
     (SELECT date, grob as grob_r2
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r2'
     ) TAB_2
     ON TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date;
```

In this case, you probably don't need `DATE` twice.  BigQuery supports the standard `USING` clause, which allows you to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT date, grob as grob_r1
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r1'
     ) TAB_1 JOIN
     (SELECT date, grob as grob_r2
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r2'
     ) TAB_2
     USING (date);
```

This returns three columns.

Another handy alternative -- which is not needed in this case -- is `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT TAB_1.*,
       TAB_2.* EXCEPT (date)
FROM (SELECT date, grob as grob_r1
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r1'
     ) TAB_1 JOIN
     (SELECT date, grob as grob_r2
      FROM `mytab_tbl`
      WHERE region = 'r2'
     ) TAB_2
     ON TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date;
```